# Dovecot mailbox does not allow for inferior mailboxes

Tags: sendmail, dovecot

I'm getting the following errors from Dovecot.  I've tried googling answers, but have come up with no solutions.

The errors I get are as follows.

```
Apr  4 03:03:44 usve75539 dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<peter>, method=PLAIN, rip=xxxx, lip=xxxx, mpid=4148, TLS, session=<NG8G+p8vkQB4FsJg>
Apr  4 03:03:44 usve75539 dovecot: pop3(peter): Error: Couldn't open INBOX: Mailbox doesn't allow inferior mailboxes
Apr  4 03:03:44 usve75539 dovecot: pop3(peter): Couldn't open INBOX top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/0, size=0
Apr  4 03:03:51 usve75539 dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=<peter@xyz.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=xxx, lip=xxx, TLS, session=<lW4r+p8vlAB4FsJg>
```

Guessing it has something to do with the pam authentication.

```
Apr  4 05:42:07 usve75539 auth: pam_unix(pop3:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr  4 05:42:07 usve75539 auth: pam_unix(pop3:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=peter@xyz.com rhost=xxx
```

Ok now looks like I need the contents of what is meant to go in /etc/pam.d/pop3

Any help would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which client are you using?  I expect its configuration does not match your Dovecot configuration.  IMAP is generally a better option these days.

Comment: I'm using pop3.

Answer (score 1):

The solution might depend on how you configured the `mail_location` property.
For instance if you use the `mbox` storage option, [here is an official solution](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/mbox/mboxchildfolders/?highlight=mbox%20configuration):

```
# Trick mbox configuration which allows a mail folder which contains both
# messages and sub-folders
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:LAYOUT=maildir++:INDEX=~/mail/index:CONTROL=~/mail/control
```

But if you are using `maildir` instead, [the documentation seems to assume sub-folders ("inferior mailboxes") are allowed](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/Maildir/). But [somebody else worked around the issue](https://superuser.com/questions/813362/sub-folders-in-dovecot) :

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir:LAYOUT=fs
```